# Content API for Shopping - No module named google_auth_httplib2

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, google-api-python-client

I'm following the link below with the aim of implementing a Google API for shopping:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/quickstart/making-an-api-call

but when I insert the command below:

```
python -m shopping.content.products.my-insert
```

I encounter this error:

```
No module named google_auth_httplib2
```

Whenever I run the following command however to test if google auth is installed:

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
```

I get the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem sorry would greatly appreciate everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `google-auth-httplib2` and not `google-auth-oauthlib`

```
pip install google-auth-httplib2
```